# Alt attribute in img tag html error

Tags: css, html

when i put value in alt attribute in img tag it doesn't appear over the image.I am using IE8.
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `title`. `alt` is meant to be shown when the image cannot be downloaded (also used by screen readers).

Comment: @Loktar: On a related note - "In the world of Kung Fu, speed decides the winner" - Kungfu Hustle

Answer (score 2):

That's how it's supposed to work. If you are asking "how do I make a tooltip?" then the answer is to use the `title` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't. The alt text is displayed only if the image can't be loaded for some reason or another (e.g. wrong file path, corrupted, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The `alt` attribute is an an alternative if for some reason the user is unable to view the image. Some browsers have chosen to display the `alt` tag in a similar way to how the `title` attribute is used. To test it, change the `src` of the image to be incorrect and you should see the `alt` text.

See [W3Schools - ALT Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp) for more details

Comment: I've corrected the misuse of "tag" for "attribute" and fixed the citation. The [W3C](http://w3.org/) are responsible for the specs, but you are linking to W3Schools which is an unrelated and [dreadful](http://w3fools.com/) tutorial/reference site.